# Finding the 'state' of a network socket, and reading from it appropriately

Tags: sockets

I'm trying to understand the various 'states' of a TCP socket (/connection) with respect to:

- whether I can read from/write to the socket
- what system calls I should use to read/write

Suppose, for example, I have a TCP socket to the www.example.com website.  An unknown number of HTTP requests (possibly none) with unknown content have been sent via the socket.  It isn't known what system calls have been made to the socket already.  Further requests will be sent via the socket if possible (i.e., irreversible closing of the socket should be avoided).

In terms of reading from the socket/writing to it

- what information do I need to know about the socket?
- how do I obtain it through system calls?
- for each 'state', what is the appropriate system call for reading from the socket?

Comment: The motivation behind this question is that I've spent some time looking at this (in Ruby - but I don't think that's relevant) and along the way I have found:

- calls that only work if the socket has been closed for writing
- calls the are dependent on whether buffering has been used
- calls that don't work if other calls have been run
- 'non-blocking' calls that appear to block anyway.
I'm hoping that someone will be able to summarise the situation at a fundamental level. Even a good resource would be massively useful.

Comment: The appropriate system call for reading is `read`.